# How to read on local port repeatedly using php?

Tags: php, sockets, amazon-ec2, instance

I have searched a lot on this topic and tried a lot of thingd but still i'm stuck.

I have an ec2 instance on which another instance is sending some data through tcp on a specific port. I am using the following code..

```
  $host = "x.x.x.x";
    $port = 2048;


    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)  ;

if (!socket_setopt($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) 
{
        echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
        exit;
} 
    $result=socket_bind($socket, $host, $port);
    $result = socket_listen($socket, 3);

    $spawn = socket_accept($socket);

    $input = socket_read($spawn, 84);

echo $input;

    socket_close($spawn);
    socket_close($socket);
```

Sometimes it runs , sometimes it doesn't , it gives error at socket_bind():

```
"socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use"
```

I'v looked a lot on this but nothing has worked...

If someone comes upt with something.. plz help..!

thanx
mayur

Comment: change your port and try ....

Comment: Are you sure that you only have one instance of your php script running at the same time? It sounds like you run it more than once. (You can only bind one instance to a specific port.)

Comment: @stewe Thanx for your comment....my php script can run more than once . Does that mean that it'll not bind to the port. I'm closing the socket each time. What's the alternative..?

Comment: If you run it more than once, in serial, that should not be a problem, but starting it a second time, while the first script still hasn't reached `socket_close()`, is.

I'd reverse the roles of server/client, so your script "plays" the client when fetching the data and not the "server" like in your example.

Comment: How can I reverse the roles .. can you please elaborate.... 
Even if once the script has finished execution , it puts the port in `TIME_WAIT` and then in `CLOSE_WAIT` state .. I still get the same error...

Comment: I tried a client side socket script and it worked fine. Thanx @stewe for your suggestion